# Emulate split() with dplyr group_by: return a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, split, dplyr

I have a large dataset that chokes `split()` in R. I am able to use `dplyr` group_by (which is a preferred way anyway) but I am unable to persist the resulting `grouped_df` as a list of data frames, a format required by my consecutive processing steps (I need to coerce to `SpatialDataFrames` and similar).

consider a sample dataset:

```
df = as.data.frame(cbind(c("a","a","b","b","c"),c(1,2,3,4,5), c(2,3,4,2,2)))
listDf = split(df,df$V1)
```

returns

```
$a
   V1 V2 V3
 1  a  1  2
 2  a  2  3

$b
   V1 V2 V3
 3  b  3  4
 4  b  4  2

$c
   V1 V2 V3
 5  c  5  2
```

I would like to emulate this with `group_by` (something like `group_by(df,V1)`) but this returns one, `grouped_df`. I know that `do` should be able to help me, but I am unsure about usage (also see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796829/how-can-dplyr-generate-data-frame-for-each-group-after-the-group-by-opration/26798420?noredirect=1#comment55284955_26798420) for a discussion.)

Note that split names each list by the name of the factor that has been used to establish this group - this is a desired function (ultimately, bonus kudos for a way to extract these names from the list of dfs).

Comment: Why is `group_by` preferred over `split`? Because it was written by Hadley? `group_by` has it's place and it isn't designed to split a data set into different data frames, while `split` is designed to achieve exactly that.

Comment: Nope, not because it was written by hadley, but because it completes - and fast. I have a dataset that is a df of 400mb, and split results in a monstrosity ( not sure why it inflates the size), and crashes R when saving. This is a training dataset, the real one is then a 8.5GB dataset (1GB as RData). Group worked, split failed. I tried bigsplit, but did not manage to get it work either. Still, back to the question - how to do this with group_by ( and dplyr)?

Comment: Again, `group_by` wasn't designed to split a data set to separate data sets. `do` will be probably much slower than `split`. `split` is fully vectorized and compiled function and I don't see why it will slower than any other alternative.

Comment: So I assume that you have some function say `f()` that you want to apply to each data.frame in your list of data.frames (generated by `split`). If that is the case, the alternative dplyr-route (without splitting) would be something like `df %>% group_by(V1) %>% do(f(.))` assuming `f()` returns a data.frame. Otherwise you might need something like `df %>% group_by(V1) %>% do(data.frame(f(.)))`. If you really want to create a list, stick with `split`, as commented by David.

Comment: You are right. I need to apply a function that generates a totally different object - a SpatialDataFrame. Thus I assume that at this stage of the workflow, I have to get "out" of the dplyr workflow. Hence I want a list of dfs, that I can later iterate through and do whatever I need. I tried a simple hack `%>% do(as.data.frame(.))` but that did not work  (and I did not know how to make each group append to one large `list()`. Hints welcome. I tried something like: `xx<- group_by(df,V1) %>% do(data.frame(function(x) {coordinates(x)=(~V2+V3)}))
` where `coordinates` is from `library(sp)`

Answer (score 32):

**group_split in dplyr:**

Dplyr has implemented `group_split`:
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_split.html

It splits a dataframe by a groups, returns a list of dataframes. Each of these dataframes are subsets of the original dataframes defined by categories of the splitting variable.

For example. Split the dataset `iris` by the variable `Species`, and calculate summaries of each sub-dataset:

```
> iris %>% 
+     group_split(Species) %>% 
+     map(summary)
[[1]]
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width          Species  
 Min.   :4.300   Min.   :2.300   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.100   setosa    :50  
 1st Qu.:4.800   1st Qu.:3.200   1st Qu.:1.400   1st Qu.:0.200   versicolor: 0  
 Median :5.000   Median :3.400   Median :1.500   Median :0.200   virginica : 0  
 Mean   :5.006   Mean   :3.428   Mean   :1.462   Mean   :0.246                  
 3rd Qu.:5.200   3rd Qu.:3.675   3rd Qu.:1.575   3rd Qu.:0.300                  
 Max.   :5.800   Max.   :4.400   Max.   :1.900   Max.   :0.600                  

[[2]]
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length   Petal.Width          Species  
 Min.   :4.900   Min.   :2.000   Min.   :3.00   Min.   :1.000   setosa    : 0  
 1st Qu.:5.600   1st Qu.:2.525   1st Qu.:4.00   1st Qu.:1.200   versicolor:50  
 Median :5.900   Median :2.800   Median :4.35   Median :1.300   virginica : 0  
 Mean   :5.936   Mean   :2.770   Mean   :4.26   Mean   :1.326                  
 3rd Qu.:6.300   3rd Qu.:3.000   3rd Qu.:4.60   3rd Qu.:1.500                  
 Max.   :7.000   Max.   :3.400   Max.   :5.10   Max.   :1.800                  

[[3]]
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width          Species  
 Min.   :4.900   Min.   :2.200   Min.   :4.500   Min.   :1.400   setosa    : 0  
 1st Qu.:6.225   1st Qu.:2.800   1st Qu.:5.100   1st Qu.:1.800   versicolor: 0  
 Median :6.500   Median :3.000   Median :5.550   Median :2.000   virginica :50  
 Mean   :6.588   Mean   :2.974   Mean   :5.552   Mean   :2.026                  
 3rd Qu.:6.900   3rd Qu.:3.175   3rd Qu.:5.875   3rd Qu.:2.300                  
 Max.   :7.900   Max.   :3.800   Max.   :6.900   Max.   :2.500
```

It is also very helpful for debugging a calculations on nested dataframes, because it is an quick way to "see" what is going on "inside" the calculations on nested dataframes.

Comment: This was the easiest to implement answer for me as of right now!

Comment: Plus: if you want to have names for your lists. Use the function `named_group_split()` from here https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4223

Answer (score 17):

Comparing the base, `plyr` and `dplyr` solutions, it still seems the base one is much faster!

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)   

df <- data_frame(Group1=rep(LETTERS, each=1000),
             Group2=rep(rep(1:10, each=100),26), 
             Value=rnorm(26*1000))

microbenchmark(Base=df %>%
             split(list(.$Group2, .$Group1)),
           dplyr=df %>% 
             group_by(Group1, Group2) %>% 
             do(data = (.)) %>% 
             select(data) %>% 
             lapply(function(x) {(x)}) %>% .[[1]],
           plyr=dlply(df, c("Group1", "Group2"), as.tbl),
           times=50)
```

Gives:

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
  Base 12.82725  13.38087  16.21106  14.58810  17.14028  41.67266    50
  dplyr 25.59038 26.66425  29.40503  27.37226  28.85828  77.16062   50
  plyr 99.52911  102.76313 110.18234 106.82786 112.69298 140.97568    50
```

Comment: You used `split` incorrectly. `split` only accepts a single argument for the factoring. Instead of `split(.$Group2, .$Group1)` write `split(list(.$Group2, .$Group1))`. Incidentally, this makes the result for `Base` 20x slower on my machine.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out! I corrected it, and indeed, base becomes slower, though still faster than others.

Answer (score 14):

To 'stick' to dplyr, you can also use `plyr` instead of `split`:

```
library(plyr)

dlply(df, "V1", identity)
#$a
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  a  1  2
#2  a  2  3

#$b
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  b  3  4
#2  b  4  2

#$c
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  c  5  2
```

Comment: How using `plyr` is sticking with `dplyr`?

Comment: Thank you very much. This results in exactly what I wanted, and completes fast. I will not mark it as the proper answer as I am still interested how the result of group_by can be exported as list of data frames, but thank you - you have solved my problem and I learnt something! Interesting thing is, that from a 380Mb dataset, the result claims to be a 340Gb list! I hope I can save it, seems weird - but it completes very fast, in about 5 mins.

Comment: Had the same structured problem and couldn't go through with `my.data %>% group_by(colA) %>% do( . , function.that.returns.list)` because `dplyr` expects the results back in a `data.frame`. Using your apporach worked perfectly `results <- dlply(my.data, "colA", function.that.returns.list)`

Comment: why there is nothing like `split_by` similar to `gorup_by`

Answer (score 9):

You can get a list of data frames from `group_by` using `do` as long as you name the new column where the data frames will be stored and then pipe that column into `lapply`.

```
listDf = df %>% group_by(V1) %>% do(vals=data.frame(.)) %>% select(vals) %>% lapply(function(x) {(x)})
listDf[[1]]
#[[1]]
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  a  1  2
#2  a  2  3

#[[2]]
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  b  3  4
#2  b  4  2

#[[3]]
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  c  5  2
```

Comment: with recent version of `tidyr` (0.4.1), you could replace `do(vals=data.frame(.))` by `nest()`. `vals` will be named `data` by default

Comment: note that using `nest()` in place of `do` isn't strictly the same thing; the resulting tables have only columns V2 and V3; the grouping variable is lost.

Comment: an identical but slightly shorter version would be: `df %>% group_by(V1) %>% do(data = (.)) %>% select(data) %>% map(identity)`

Comment: Using `dplyr 0.5.0.9000` or later, it's possible to simplify @cboettig 's solution even further: `df %>% group_by(V1) %>% do(data=(.)) %>% pull(data)`.

Answer (score 8):

Since *dplyr 0.8* you can use `group_split`

```r
library(dplyr)
df = as.data.frame(cbind(c("a","a","b","b","c"),c(1,2,3,4,5), c(2,3,4,2,2)))
df %>% group_by(V1) %>% group_split()
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   V1    V2    V3   
#>   <fct> <fct> <fct>
#> 1 a     1     2    
#> 2 a     2     3    
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   V1    V2    V3   
#>   <fct> <fct> <fct>
#> 1 b     3     4    
#> 2 b     4     2    
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   V1    V2    V3   
#>   <fct> <fct> <fct>
#> 1 c     5     2
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `dplyr 0.5.0.9000`, the shortest solution that uses `group_by()` is probably to follow `do` with a `pull`:

```
df %>% group_by(V1) %>% do(data=(.)) %>% pull(data)
```

Note that, unlike `split`, this doesn't name the resulting list elements. If this is desired, then you would probably want something like

```
df %>% group_by(V1) %>% do(data = (.)) %>% with( set_names(data, V1) )
```

To editorialize a little, I agree with the folks saying that `split()` is the better option. Personally, I always found it annoying that I have to type the name of the data frame twice (e.g., `split( potentiallylongname, potentiallylongname$V1 )`), but the issue is easily sidestepped with the pipe:

```
df %>% split( .$V1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `group_map` per `group_by` and if you want to keep the names per group to each list of dataframe, you could use `set_names` from `purrr` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  group_map(~.x)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   V2    V3   
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 1     2    
#> 2 2     3    
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   V2    V3   
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 3     4    
#> 2 4     2    
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   V2    V3   
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 5     2

library(purrr)
df %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  group_map(~.x) %>% 
  set_names(unique(df$V1))
#> $a
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   V2    V3   
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 1     2    
#> 2 2     3    
#> 
#> $b
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   V2    V3   
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 3     4    
#> 2 4     2    
#> 
#> $c
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   V2    V3   
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 5     2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>