# split into multiple subset of dataframes with dplyr:group_by?

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there any way to split one dataframe into subsets of dataframes with dplyr according to group_by groups?

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% (codes?)
```

thank a lot!

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: I'm expecting a list of dataframes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775239/emulate-split-with-dplyr-group-by-return-a-list-of-data-frames

Comment: The point of `group_by` is that it _doesn't_ split, but allows you to do operations as if you had. If you do want it split, use `split`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, not that you'd really want to - but you can do it with `tidyr`, which is *nearly* the same thing.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data(iris)

iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    nest() %>%
    select(data) %>%
    unlist(recursive = F)

#> $data1
#> # A tibble: 50 x 4
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
#> 2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
#> 
#> $data2
#> # A tibble: 50 x 4
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4
#> 2           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5
#> 
#> $data3
#> # A tibble: 50 x 4
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1           6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5
#> 2           5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9
```