# split data set based on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, list, vector, split, purrr

I have a data frame and a vector, and I want to split the data frame into multiple lists if the value appears in the vector.

For example, here's the vector:

```
foods_to_serve <- c("Sweets", "Bitter")
```

Here's the data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
problem <- tibble(name = c("Angela", "Claire", "Justin", "Rachel"), 
                  favfood1 = c("Sweets", "Salty", "Sweets", "Salty"), 
                  favfood2 = c("Bitter", "Sweets", "Salty", NA), 
                  favfood3 = c("Salty", NA, NA, NA), 
                  hunger = c("high", "high", "low", "low"))
```

I want R to split this into lists that only include foods that appears in the food to serve list. Also, people can be on multiple lists and some people may be excluded entirely.

To be more concrete, I would get a list that looks like this:

```
[1] 
Food_to_serve  name      hunger
Sweets        Angela     high
Sweets        Claire     high
Sweets        Justin     low

[2]
Food_to_serve  name      hunger
Bitter         Angela    high
```

I know that I can use split(), but I'm not sure how to make it iterate over these various columns. I think that I might need to use a pmap function from purrr, but I'm not sure. I don't mind if the final lists retain if something was their first, second, or third favorite food, but I do need it to include the rest of the information in the original data frame. If possible, a tidy solution would be appreciated.

I've also tried using %in%, but I also don't know how to make it go over multiple columns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775239/emulate-split-with-dplyr-group-by-return-a-list-of-data-frames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(problem,key = favfood,value = type,favfood1:favfood3,na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(type %in% foods_to_serve) %>% 
  group_split(type)
```

Note that `group_split` is still marked as being somewhat experimental so it's behavior might change down the road.

Comment: `filter(type %in% foods_to_serve)`  why we need this line?

Comment: @joran, thank you for this! One question, what if sometimes people can list 3 foods and other times, they can list 4 or more (favfood4, etc). Is there a way to modify it to do something like max(favfood) (which I know does not work)?

Comment: @J.Sabree change `favfood1:favfood3` to `-c("name","hunger")`

Comment: @M-M, the issue is that in my dataset, these variables are in the middle, but sometimes other variables get added or subtracted. I'm trying to find a way to make it resistant to user error.

Comment: EDIT: I just discovered that you can use contains() within gather. Instead favfood1:favfood3, another option is to do contains("favfood") for the same effect. Thanks again @joran!